# Finding N partitions of number M with min and max partitions sizes

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This code was created for a game project in which 10 houses need to be populated with 16 people. I wanted the distribution to be random, with no more than 3 and no less than 1 person per house and no remaining people or houses.

[JSbin link](http://jsbin.com/qokinoteje/edit?js,console)

```
function getRandomPartitionsFromNumber(number, parts, min, max) {
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    var part = randomIntFromInterval(min, max);
    result.push(part);
  }
  var sum = result.reduce(add, 0);

  // If the sum is greater than the number, we need to iterate through
  // the result and remove some numbers until it's equal
  while (sum > number) {
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i] > min) {
        result[i]--;
        sum = result.reduce(add, 0);
        if (sum === number) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    sum = result.reduce(add, 0);
  }

  while (sum < number) {
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i] < max) {
        result[i]++;
        sum = result.reduce(add, 0);
        if (sum === number) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function randomFromArray(array) {
  return array[randomIntFromInterval(0, array.length - 1)];
}

function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(getRandomPartitionsFromNumber(16, 10, 1, 3));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have done your algorithm, you could just apply the same operation to your `sum` variable, rather than reducing the entire array.

```
  while (sum > number) {
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i] > min) {
        result[i]--;
        sum--
        if (sum === number) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    sum = result.reduce(add, 0);
  }
```

Additionally, the last `sum = result.reduce` is not needed here, as any change in the result array is subsequently reflected in the sum variable a row lower.

```
  while (sum > number) {
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i] > min) {
        result[i]--;
        sum--
        if (sum === number) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Lastly, keep in mind if you were to feed your code an impossible situation ("stuff 5 people into 1 house where each house can only contain 3 people at most"), you will get an infinite loop. It's up to you to decide how to handle this.